# Making faster ListView with images using multi-threading (Android API 10)

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, lazy-loading

I have searched for answers but none seemed to help in my case.
App min sdk - **API 10**

Problem - slow ListView with images.

Reasons - data loading is on the UI thread (without images everything works smoothly) and probbavly the way I get the image resource id.

---

I have a ListView with two TextViews and an ImageView. I populate the ListView texts from an inserted database with SQLiteAssetHelper.

The table example:

```
specie_table
_id | LITHUANIAN          |   LATIN
0   | Paprastasis varnėnas| Sturnus vulgaris
1   | Juodasis strazdas   | Turdus merula
```

### Image loading

I have PNG images saved in the *drawable* folder.

I get the image resource id from the data in the database:

in specie_table.db "Regulus regulus" -> getImageName(name) returns "regulus_regulus" -> getResId(name, class) returns the drawable id -> setImage(ImageView, name) sets the resource for the ImageView

**Should I make a different approach?**

---

List_item.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_bird_grey"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:text="Lithuanian title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:text="Latin title"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

SpecieCursorAdapter.java

```
public class SpecieCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


SpecieCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    SpecieHolder holder = null;

    holder = new SpecieHolder();
    holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
    holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

    String nameLT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SpecieTable.LIT_COL));
    String nameLOT = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SpecieTable.LAT_COL));


    holder.txtTitle1.setText(nameLT);
    holder.txtTitle2.setText(nameLOT);
    setImage(holder.imgIcon, nameLOT);  //this makes everything laggy but i dont know how to make it as seperate thread.

}
static class SpecieHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle1;
    TextView txtTitle2;
}

public void setImage(ImageView mainImage, String resource){ //these methods are for getting the image resource id from String (latin name).

    int id = getResId(getImageName(resource), R.drawable.class);
    if(id != -1)
        mainImage.setImageResource(id);
    else
        mainImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bird_grey);

}
public int getResId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
}
public String getImageName(String resource){
    String string = resource.toLowerCase();
    string = string.replace(' ', '_');
    string = string.replace(".", "");
    return string;
}}
```

---

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "bird info";
ListView listView;
ListActivity context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Habitats habitat = Habitats.detachFrom(intent); //this is an enum type sent as String, converted back to enum.

    Cursor cursor;

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    cursor = databaseAccess.getCursorByHabitat(habitat);
    databaseAccess.close();

    SpecieCursorAdapter adapter = new SpecieCursorAdapter(this, cursor);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);// how to seperate the image loading?

}
```

Examples would help very mutch! I will insert any needed extra code.

Comment: `Faster ListView` ... sounds like `RecyclerView`, to me.

Comment: Have you tried using an image loader library? Glide is quite proficient in image loading! https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Are you loading images that are saved in the database?  If yes, where is the database?  on the phone or online? does the database contain the actual image, or just a url link to the image?

Comment: @BooberBunz images are pasted into the drawable folder. If one specie is Regulus regulus the image name is regulus_regulus.png so i have the method **setImage(ImageView mainImage, String resource)** in the class SpecieCursorsAdapter to find the needed resource according to the String name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Neil and @shelll I used the **Glide** library. I modified my code accordingly:

added to the build.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

modified the bindView() method by changing

```
setImage(holder.imgIcon, nameLOT);
```

to

```
int imageId = getResId(getImageName(nameLOT), R.drawable.class);
if(imageId == -1)
    imageId = R.drawable.ic_bird_grey;

Glide
        .with(holder.imgIcon.getContext())
        .load(imageId)
        .into(holder.imgIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Volley HTTP library for faster data transferring and image loading.
Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.

Follow these links

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

[An example listview with image loading using Volley library](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an existing lib as proposed by @abhilash or implement it on your own

In android displaying an item with an image in a listview works like this (example):

- The listview needs to display item that is at position #35
- The listview asks its adapter for a filled listviewitemview for the item that is at position #35
- listviewitemview is either recycled from an old listviewitemview that is not visible any more or a new listviewitemview is created
- each listviewitemview has a corresponding viewHolder with imageID and a bitmap-gui element
- the image in the listviewitemview is initally loaded with a placeholder-image that will be visible until the imagload is complete.
- the adapter initiates loading the image in the background (async-task) that gets the viewHolder with imageID.
- when loading of the image in the background is finished the viewholder-gui element gets the loaded image.

GridView and ListView work the same way.

Here is a working example from [APhotoManager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager). It contains a [GalleryCursorFragment](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/blob/FDroid/app/src/main/java/de/k3b/android/androFotoFinder/gallery/cursor/GalleryCursorFragment.java) with the gridview with an embedded GridCellViewHolder

Answer (score -1):

For asynchronous images loading (and caching) use a library created for that, like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/)